# Intercept UI change *before* reaching the view model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

**Question:** Are there any ways to intercept a change in the UI before the change gets to the view model? Specifically I need something that will work with a `ComboBox`. There are plenty of ways of detecting that something in the UI has changed and  then "cancelling" by changing it back (for example: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608071/wpf-cancel-a-user-selection-in-a-databound-listbox), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283074/wpf-databinding-cancelled-property-change-combobox-misaligns)), but these all have one of these two drawbacks:

1. The underlying model is changed and then changed back instead of the change really being canceled.
2. The cancelling happens in the view model so the UI for cancelling also has to go in the view model.

**Background:** I have a form with a `ComboBox` with some `Foos`. The user should be free to change the selected `Foo` (once the choose a `Foo` they should not be locked into keeping it), but changing the selected `Foo` might invalidate some of the other setting in the view model that the user has chosen. The user will get some warning, probably a message box, saying "Are you sure you want to change the Foo?", and choosing to not change the `Foo` should cancel the change. The problem with changing the value of the selected `Foo` and then changing it back is that the logic for deciding what needs to be invalidated ought to be hooked into setting the VM backing property (possibly the `NotifyPropertyChanged(Foo)` or just next to it) and so the other settings get invalidated whether the change is cancelled or not.

**Orthogonal questions that solve my problem:**

1. Am I attempting to bend the MVVM paradigm in a way that it is not supposed to be bent? Should I be looking for a way of moving the cancel UI to the UI and keep the cancel behaviour in the view model?
2. Is the assertion that "changing then changing back doesn't work" not accurate? Is there somewhere to hook into later after the changing back has happened to then kick off (or suppress) invalidation?

Answer (score 0):

Noone says that your view model has to immediately forward every change to the model.

I'd trigger the "do you really want to change this?" dialog from the view model, and if the user answers "yes" then change the model (and invalidate other properties if necessary), otherwise revert the change in the view model and invalidate nothing.

Comment: Looks like I have not quite been clear in the question. The invalidation happens in the ViewModel (and so the UI gets updated by the invalid settings removed). The Model only has the valid settings written to it on OKing out of the form. I'll update the question

Comment: Looks like I haven't been too clear either - there's no problem if a bound property in the view model is invalidated. The view model can restore that data when the user choses to cancel the edit, because its still in the model. Just delay the change in the model until the user clicks ok.